# Why doesn't this jQuery .each loop through json data correctly?

Tags: jquery, json, loops

Here's my ajax call:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'url-to-json',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: 'false',
    data: { lat: lat, lng: lng }
}).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(a) {
        alert(data[a]);
    });
});
```

Here's the json it's iterating over:

```
[
{"Id":"4c75bd5666be6dcb9f70c10f","Name":"BXtra","EnglishName":null,"Lat":35.7515869140625,"Lng":139.33872985839844},

{"Id":"4c5160a1d2a7c9b655d51211","Name":"セブンイレブン 武蔵野台店","EnglishName":null,"Lat":35.750205993652344,"Lng":139.33448791503906},

...
]
```

But instead of actually giving me access to the properties of each item in the json array, it literally loops through each character in the array, one by one.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try passing a `success` callback to the `.ajax` function instead of using `.done()`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried this too. Still loops through each character of the json result, one-by-one.

Comment: I also suspect the problem is with your JSON, then. Are you sure the JSON you're getting is parseable?

Comment: Thanks, manually calling `$.parseJSON(json)` works. I'll have to look closer at the MIME type of the return.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can modify your `$.each` function in two ways:

```
$.each(data, function(index,el) {
    // el = object in array
    // access attributes: el.Id, el.Name, etc
});
```

Or,

```
$.each(data, function() {
    // this = object in array
    // access attributes: this.Id, this.Name, etc
});
```

If `data` is a string within your `done` function and not an object, then you'll need to run

```
data = $.parseJSON(data)
```

before your `$.each` loop

Comment: I tried this... it appears every el is referencing each individual character of the json... almost as if it were a string, and the loop iterates of each individual character rather than each entry in the array.

Comment: Oh, in that case, `data` is probably coming back as a string, and not as an object. Run `alert(typeof data)` from within your `done` function. If it comes back as `string`, then `data` isn't being converted into an object. I don't know if `.done()` uses the `dataType` attribute of `$.ajax` or whether it only uses the raw response

Comment: That was it... even though I set the type to JSON, it wasn't parsing it... thanks!

Comment: @Chad did you check the MIME type returned by the server? http://docs.jquery.com/Specifying_the_Data_Type_for_AJAX_Requests

Answer (score 4):

Use `this` to refer to current element inside `.each`:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'url-to-json',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: 'false',
    data: { lat: lat, lng: lng }
}).done(function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
        alert(this.Id);
    });
});
```

Comment: To add explanation, the OP's method was retrieving the *object* back when using `data[a]` which still needed to reference a property of that object. OP's method would have been fine if they just modified it to something like `data[a].Id`, `data[a]['Id']`, or alike. However, while inside the `.each` `this==object[key]`, that is to say `this==data[a]`

Comment: using `this` still iterates over each character of the JSON individually. If I `alert(this)` it show each character, one by one. If I `alert(this.Id)` it shows undefined.

Comment: I have verified it and it works. Are you sure that you've got correct data in `done`?

Comment: Appeared even though I set the type as JSON, it wasn't parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your server is not returning the right MIME type for JSON ('application/json') and JQuery is interpreting it as just a string?

Answer (score 0):

Using success always works for me:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: 'url-to-json',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  cache: 'false',
  data: { lat: lat, lng: lng },
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
      alert(this.Id);
    });
  }
});
```

Forcing a parse of the JSON would be: `jQuery.parseJSON( json )` as a temporary fix if the dataType is playing up...